# Support for selection of kaa application key during execution

Tags: kaa

I am making multiple clients accessing same Kaa application. Consider it as fork of a process. As I can understand, Kaa server differentiate b/w clients based on the hash which is part of kaa public key. So essentially, for having multiple clients, I should be having multiple kaa public-private keys generated.
Now, questions comes here. As by default this key is taken by default and there is no option to select key for an application (if I haven't missed any such update), how can we achieve it. I can add same support within Kaa SDK at client side but I am afraid if any future update will make my code void or there will be effort needed to maintain my code during Kaa version upgrade.

Touching Kaa SDK is my last option, so is there any way Kaa could differentiate b/w clients?

Comment: Please, move your answer from question section to answer section in order to other users can easily find one.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of question in other thread for its use case, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kaaproject/qwjVIWBMp8M. As when we run Kaa application, Kaa public/private key is generated in the same folder from where we do run the application. My answer of use case is:

I am making Node-RED interface for Kaa application. And there could be multiple Node-RED nodes and each will be separate client to the Kaa server but using the same kaa client application. So, to make all these clients separate, I need to create separate pub/private key. Since we are not executing Kaa app binary here directly, which is the usual case. Now, how to make sure for generating separate Kaa pub/private key. This is not the ideal case, as like in Kaa demo app, but an interesting scenario. If needed with bit more details, then I can share github initial code as well for my target.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this new [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/Java/#basic-api-overview). You can resolve this problem with using 
***KaaClientProperties*** class where you can specify **PrivateKeyFileName** and **PublickKeyFileName**. Also you can generate your own key pairs for your clients. Specify different names of key files and you can run all your clients in the same folder without conflicts.

Comment: Java Kaa SDK provides API for it. Need to figure out if C++ also does.